# vm ubuntu 20.04 consume disk so fast

Tags: 20.04

I had some problem with the disk space of my virtual machine (ubuntu 20.04). I had only VS code(with liveshare extention), cloudflare, xampp and github desktop that's running on my machine but after 1 day when i check my machine it only had 500mb space left. Is there a way to check what program eating my disk space? i originally had 10gb space.

Comment: The [system requirements](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on the page where Ubuntu is downloaded recommends 25GB as a minimum. If you opted for 10, then the problem is with the configuration you specified, not anything on the machine itself 